Inquiry on Consolidating Mobile Push SDK Notification Handling Functions
https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-configureforpush.html
The following SDK functions pass user information in the Mobile Push SDK guide from the link above:
// MobilePush SDK: REQUIRED IMPLEMENTATION
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_setNotificationUserInfo(userInfo)

completionHandler(.newData)

}


// MobilePush SDK: REQUIRED IMPLEMENTATION
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

// Required: tell the MarketingCloudSDK about the notification. This will collect MobilePush analytics

// and process the notification on behalf of your application.

MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_setNotificationRequest(response.notification.request)

completionHandler()

}

Both of the above functions are listed as mandatory. However, from iOS 10 and later, if both functions are implemented, only the latter function is executed, meaning the first function is not executed.
The current app developer says they will no longer use the didReceiveRemoteNotification function due to internal work.
I am wondering if it would be acceptable to remove the first function and move its content to the second function. I would appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue.
